# Rewriting / Redirecting URLs using .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am looking for the correct code to place in a .htaccess file that will redirect this:

```
http://www.website.com/title_of_a_post_003424.html
```

to look like this

```
http://www.website.com/title-of-a-post/
```

Things to note about the change:

1. The title of each post will be different, and the numbers will be different.
2. Titles will be up to 40 characters. Numbers will always be 6 digits in length
3. Underscores are replaced with dashes
4. `.html` is removed and replaced with a forward slash

Lastly, if at all possible this change would also use a 301 redirect so that search engines replace old links with new links.

All help or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)_[0-9]{6}\.html$ /$1/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2
```

---

EDIT:

To stick with mod_rewrite as to not get affected by wordpress rewrite rules, you need to add these **before** your wordpress rules:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)_[0-9]{6}\.html$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This code works wonderfully! It does exactly as I requested. Unfortunately, I need this to also work with the wordpress .htaccess redirect which makes "Pretty Permalinks". The wordpress code can be found here http://randomtype.ca/blog/the-wordpress-htaccess-file-explained/ Do you know of a way to mix your code with this wordpress code?